# Building a query, that will show a model method as a result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several models: `Provider`, `Casino`, `Rating` and `Casino_provider`

**Provider.rb:**

```
class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :casino_providers
  has_many :casinos, through: :casino_providers
end
```

**Casino.rb:**

```
class Casino < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :casino_providers
  has_many :providers, through: :casino_providers

  def average_rating
    if ratings.count == 0
      ratings.sum(:score).to_f / 1
    else
      ratings.sum(:score).to_f / ratings.count
    end
  end

end
```

**Rating.rb:**

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :casino
end
```

**Casino_provider.rb:**

```
class CasinoProvider < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :casino
  belongs_to :provider
end
```

What I'm going to do, is to show the casino, that belongs to provider with the highest average rating. I tried to do smth. like this in rails console:

```
provider = Provider.all[1] #This is the provider, that has a casino in db
provider.casinos.where(casinos: {average_rating: :asc}) #Gives me an error: 'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column casinos.average_rating does not exist'
```

As `average_rating` is not a column in the casinos table, how can I use this method in a query? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
provider.casinos.order('average_rating asc')
```

One more thing. `provider = Provider.all[1]` will take much time to execute. Try find record with ID instead. `provider = Provider.find(ID)`

If average rating is class method, Then you can't run it using where clause. You should better use sort_by method like below:

```
provider.casinos.sort_by(&:average_rating)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives me the same error. I'm doing `provider = Provider.all[1]` only in rails console, of course, in the final version it will be smth. like this: ` <% Provider.all.each do |provider| %> <%= provider.casinos.and_so_on %> <% end %>`

Comment: `column casinos.average_rating does not exist` error suggesting average_rating does not present in casinos table. Can you please check column name properly.

Comment: `average_rating` is a method in Casino model, it is not present as a column in a db table.

Comment: Ok so where clause wont work for you here, Because it run query on db not on model so do something like this. `provider.casinos.sort_by(&:average_rating)`

Comment: Thanks, now it looks like the answer I was seeking for, but this sorting gives me the lowest average_rating first, and the highest is the last. Of course, it can be done smth like this: `provider.casinos.sort_by(&:average_rating).last`, but in a such way I can't display casinos name, as I could do it by this: `provider.casinos.sort_by(&:average_rating).take(1).pluck(:name)`

Comment: Just used `.reverse`: `provider.casinos.sort_by(&:average_rating).reverse.take(1).pluck(:name).join(' ')`